# How to alias folders for use with IIS?

Tags: windows, iis-7, windows-explorer

I have several websites that use the same base files, other than a couple off images and stylesheets.

Instead of having the same DLL's repeated all over the place, I would like to have a bin alias in each of the folders, pointing to another, central location.

I realize I could write deployment scripts to duplicate the reused folders, but hoping for another solution.

Thanks.

Comment: this belongs on server fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend putting your DLLs in the [global assembly cache](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4352/Demystifying-the-NET-Global-Assembly-Cache)